# Trigger javascript Function from Cordova Xcode plugin

Tags: xcode, cordova, phonegap-plugins

How can one trigger a function from Xcode? I'm using Cordova and creating a sample Plugin that would when a class in Xcode events registered it will trigger a `testFunction` on my javascript end?

**UPDATE**

So What I did was instantiate [ex1.0] then load [ex2.0] then on my xcode when a notification has been received call [ex3.0].

I have created this sample function
    ex1.0
    var test = function(){
    }

```
test.prototype.callbackIdx = 0;
test.prototype.callbackMap = [];


test.prototype.TestFunction = function( success ) {
   var key = 'TestFunction' + this.callbackIdx++;
   window.plugins.test.callbackMap[key] = {
       success:function(result){
         delete window.plugins.test.callbackMap[key];
         success(result);
       }
   };
   var callbackPrefix = 'window.plugins.test.callbackMap.'+key;
}


cordova.addConstructor(function(){
   if(!window.plugins){
      window.plugins = {};
   }

   window.plugins.test = test();
}

//CALLING IT ON JAVASCRIPT
ex2.0
window.plugins.test.TestFunction(
  function(result){
    console.log("DID TRIGGER! HOORAY!");
  }
);

//ON XCODE
ex3.0
window.plugins.test.callbackMap.TestFunction0.success("TEST");
```

Yet I don't see any "DID TRIGGER! HOORAY!" on my console.

Answer (score 0):

There is a writeJavaScript function that is a member of the CDVPlugin class.  Use that to execute JS from the native obj-c layer.  I have an example here: http://www.tricedesigns.com/2012/03/01/pushing-data-to-a-phonegap-web-view/

I wrote that example back in PhoneGap 1.5, but it should still work.  Keep in mind that the plugin classes have been renamed with the Cordova naming.  `PGPlugin` is now `CDVPlugin`, and in JavaScript `Phonegap.exec()` is now `cordova.exec()`.  Otherwise it should be more or less the same.

Comment: Yes, I think it was your post that I followed months before. But will clarify that what I would like to do is Xcode -> Javascript not Javascript -> Xcode.

Comment: You mean Obj-C -> JavaScript?   That post shows how to execute JS from Obj-C using the writeJavaScript method.   So, from a plugin you could do this:   [self writeJavascript:@"alert()"];     Or, you could reference the web view and use the stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString function, like this: [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"alert()"];    I've never tried to reference the callback map.